# ActiveDs.IADsMembers - Enumerate Global Groups which contain a Foreign Security Principal

Tags: .net, active-directory

I am enumerating a Domain Local Group in Active Directory using:

```
Dim de As New DirectoryEntry("path")
Dim members As IADsMembers = DirectCast(de.Invoke("Members"), IADsMembers)

members.Filter = New Object() {"user"}
'Iterate over users.
members.Filter = New Object() {"group"}
'Iterate over nested groups.
```

The Domain Local Group is not enumerating. I have checked `members.Count` which equals 1.

Having looked in Active Directory there is a Foreign Security Principal which links to a Global Group in another domain. Research suggests that the only options for `members.Filter` are `user and group`, `user` and `group`.

How can I extract the Foreign Security Principal from this collection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the most part I have chosen to use the functionality provided by `System.Directory.AccountManagement` in .NET 3.5 to enumerate a global group. If the object being enumerated is actually a Foreign Security Principal then the .NET 3.5 code does not suffice. Hopefully the following code will help someone else:

```
Private Sub EnumerateGlobalGroup(ByVal distinguishedName As String)

    Try

        Using context As New PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, GetDomainName(distinguishedName))
            Using gp As GroupPrincipal = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, IdentityType.DistinguishedName, distinguishedName)
                Dim groupMembers As PrincipalSearchResult(Of Principal) = gp.GetMembers(True)
                For Each member As Principal In groupMembers

                    Console.WriteLine(member.DisplayName)
                    Select Case member.StructuralObjectClass
                        Case "user"
                            Console.WriteLine("user")
                        Case "group"
                            Console.WriteLine("group")
                    End Select

                Next
            End Using
        End Using

    Catch ex As Exception

        If Not TypeOf ex Is PrincipalOperationException Then Throw ex

        'Get this far then enumerating Foreign Security Principal.
        Dim groupEntry As New DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" & distinguishedName)
        Dim members As Object = groupEntry.Invoke("Members")
        For Each member As Object In CType(members, IEnumerable)
            Dim memberEntry As New DirectoryEntry(member)
            Console.WriteLine(memberEntry.Name)

            Dim sid As New SecurityIdentifier(DirectCast(memberEntry.InvokeGet("objectSid"), Byte()), 0)
            Dim account As NTAccount = sid.Translate(GetType(NTAccount))
            Console.WriteLine(account.ToString)

            Dim memberDistinguishedName As String = GetDistinguishedName(account.ToString)
            EnumerateGlobalGroup(memberDistinguishedName)
        Next

    End Try

End Sub

Private Function GetDomainName(ByVal dn As String) As String

    Dim dnParts As String() = dn.Split(Char.Parse(","))
    For Each d As String In dnParts
        If d.StartsWith("DC") Then Return d.ToUpper().Replace("DC=", Nothing)
    Next
    Return Nothing

End Function

Private Function GetDistinguishedName(ByVal accountName As String) As String

    Dim nameTranslate = New ActiveDs.NameTranslate()
    nameTranslate.Set(ActiveDs.ADS_NAME_TYPE_ENUM.ADS_NAME_TYPE_NT4, accountName)

    Return nameTranslate.Get(ActiveDs.ADS_NAME_TYPE_ENUM.ADS_NAME_TYPE_1779)

End Function
```

There is probably better ways of doing this **but it works**.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that you have `foreign security principal` in your domain suggests that your group member is actually from another forest.  You need to make sure the account that you are using to run the code has permission to access the other forest.

If you are using .NET 3.5 or above, you should try using [System.DirectoryService.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx).

I think [GroupPrincipal.GetMembers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb339975.aspx) should solve your problem.  This [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb339975.aspx) includes a sample on how to use this `GroupPrincipal`.  It allows you to specify getting the members recursively or not.  It also mentions that you can get the members from different forest.

Comment: I was very excited about using all of these nice wrappers in .NET 3.5 which had slipped my mind. Turns out FindByIdentity fails if the global groups contains a FSP.